# Send Data from Activity A to Fragment One of a Tabbed Activity B

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

i need an approach how to handle this topic:
i have create a Mainactivity (A) and a Tabbed Activity (B) that contains 3 Tabs (Fragment One, Fragment Two and Fragment Tree)

how to send a string from the Mainactivity to the Fragment One  without starting the Tabbed Activity.

when i use bundle

let say:  in MainActivity

```
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", editText.getText().toString());
    BlankFragmentTab1 fragment = new BlankFragmentTab1();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag,fragment).commit();
```

and inside Fragment One i get the String with getarguments.getString("key")
 i get a nullpointerexception.
the approach works only by the communication between the Fragments and its container Activity.

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please include the error logs and the class where the error points

Comment: What do you mean "without starting the tabbed activity"? You must start the tabbed activity, because it hosts your fragments, you cannot start them without the activity. The information has to come to the activity and then to fragment in your case.

Comment: @LieForBananas: thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Yassin you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

LieForBananas is correct.

You can not interact with your FragmentOne  without calling its host activity.

However you can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) instead of Bundle for retrieving data.

Comment: i will try with the SharedPreferences... thank you Rozina